# Cipher.getInstance() and Cipher.getInit() for each message in case of random IV for AES encryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes

In a multi threaded Java application, we are using AES-256 for encryption and decryption of files to the disk. Please note that multiple threads can make concurrent calls to the encryption and decryption methods for different files.

Encryption:

```
Cipher encrypter = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, new BouncyCastleProvider());
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = getIvParamSpec(encrypter.getBlockSize());
encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
//..encrypt the data
```

Decryption:

```
Cipher decrypter = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, new BouncyCastleProvider());
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = readIvParamSpec(decrypter.getBlockSize(), is);
decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
//.. decrypt the data
```

In our understanding, it is better to use random IV for encryption instead of static/fixed IV. For this purpose, we are using SecureRandom API to generate the IV. The random IV is persisted in the encrypted file at the start.

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
byte[] iv = new byte[ivSizeBytes];
random.nextBytes(iv);
new IvParameterSpec(iv);
```

My question is, since I am using random IV for each encryption, do I need to call Cipher.getInstance() and Cipher.Init() for all the calls? For performance improvement, can these be called only once during the class initialization and then reuse the individual cipher instances to encrypt and decrypt the data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, since I am using random IV for each encryption, do I need to call Cipher.getInstance() and Cipher.Init() for all the calls?

You can reuse Cipher instances as long as you don't share them among threads. As Artjom mentioned, Cipher instances are stateful. They store both the IV but also the last ciphertext (used as next vector for CBC mode encryption) and possibly some buffered plaintext. Mixing that state with the input from different threads will result in chaos.

As you need a new random for each file encryption you do need to call `init` again after calling a `doFinal` method. Init is not that heavyweight; the one thing that can take a bit of performance is the subkey derivation for AES, but generally that's not a big issue.

Note that, although performing the encryption and decryption can be relatively heavy weight operations, the instances themselves contain very little state and `getInstance()` and `init` are relatively lightweight operations. So creating a few more `Cipher` instances - possibly with the same key - is fine for multiple threads.

---

Recreating the `BouncyCastleProvider` multiple times *is* a very bad idea, even though it probably uses some kind of singleton underneath. But basically you don't need the *Java only* Bouncy Castle implementation. The Oracle one may use AES-NI intrinsics that will directly use the AES-NI instruction set on compatible processors. That will run circles around Bouncy Castle - expect a speedup of around 7 to 13 times (!).

Comment: Thanks! Cipher.getInstance() takes around 200-300ms on our server. Is it expected performance? I will check regarding BouncyCastleProvider recreation. Can you please clarify on not needing Java only BC and using the Oracle one?

Comment: I would not be surprised if that is because the repeated instantiation of the BC provider, not the Cipher. Could you try and remove the provider from the equation  (completely removing the parameter could do it (giving you the Oracle one instead), or just sharing the provider, or using `Security.addProvideder(new BouncyCastleProvider())` and then using the name `"BC"` (etc.).

Comment: Your suggestion worked, many thanks! I have another question - Since I need to encrypt and decrypt files on disk, I am using CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream objects with cipher instances for this purpose. Is it the correct way of doing it? I can post the code, if it helps! It is taking around 8-10 seconds individually for encryption and decryption process - for 280MB file.

Comment: As you mentioned before, I will try with Oracle provider and see if that helps in performance in respect to encrypting and decryption files with Cipher*Stream. But it will be great if you have any recommendation here!

Comment: Changing the provider doesn't make any difference, it is still taking around 8-10 seconds individually for encryption and decryption process - for 280MB file. I have tried with no provider, BC, SunJCE - with same result.

Comment: Yes, you can use `CipherInputStream` and the outputstream for that. I personally would look into memory mapping though (in Java NIO). With regards to the speed, I/O operations also take their toll. Could you place a comment with your current runtime environment (CPU, OS and Java runtime)?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you need to use a different `Cipher` instance for each thread, because they are stateful. If you don't, then threads can break the ciphertext of other threads.

Let's assume we have two threads `t1` and `t2` which want to encrypt two plaintexts `p1_1 | p1_2` and `p2_1 | p2_1` (split on block boundary). Let's take CBC as an example:

```
time........................................................................
root    1. init with IV                           
t1          2. E(p1_1 XOR IV) = c1_1          4. E(p1_2 XOR c2_1) = c1_2
t2              3. E(p2_1 XOR c1_1) = c2_1        5. E(p2_2 XOR c1_2) = c2_2
```

`c1_1` is ok, but `c2_1` is not ok, because the state from `t1` was used for start the encryption. It is as though the encryption was initialized with `c1_1` as the IV.

This example works only for CBC mode, but other modes of operation are similar. If we assume that encryption happens *only* block-wise, then you could just use ECB mode in a thread-safe fashion, but this is only an illusion, because you cannot be sure that the implementation only handles the internal state block-wise and not byte-wise.

Comment: Thanks! Are we right in our understanding that we need to use random IV for each data that is encrypted? Though not recommended, if we use static/fix IV, can we then reuse preinitialized cipher instances again and again?

Comment: No, it doesn't make a difference whether the IV is static or random.